# Not able to understand shallow copy

Tags: python, deep-copy, shallow-copy

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> id(a[0]) == id(b[0])
True
>>> b[0] = 99
>>> id(a[0]) == id(b[0])
False
```

I understand that to make a shallow copy we can use slicing and also that there is a copy module. But why does writing to the index of "b" change the id.

Comment: You're checking the id of the first element of b, then you change what the first element of b refers to, then the id of the first element of b changes - why wouldn't it?  The ids of the lists a and b don't change, just the id of the first element.

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy "The disadvantage is if you modify the memory address that one of B's fields point to, you are also modifying what A's fields point to." Why does'nt a[0] get changed in this case ?? Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **Part 1:  Why did calling `b[0] = 99` cause `a[0] == b[0] >> False`?**

The answer to your question is that when you do `b[0] = 99`, you do not "modify the memory address that one of B's fields point to", you actually change *where* one of B's fields point.

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

Now `a` contains a reference to a `list` object, which in turn contains three references to three `int` objects.

```
b = a[:]
```

now b refers to a `list` object (not the same one as `a` refers to), and contains three references to three `int` objects, the same ones that `a` refers to.

```
id(a) == id(b)
#False
```

False, because `a` and `b` are references to different `list` objects.

```
id(a[0]) == id(b[0])
#True
```

True, because `a[0]` is a reference to the `1` object, and so is `b[0]`.  There is only one `1` object, and it is referred to by `a[0]` and `b[0]`

```
b[0] = 99  
# ^^^^^^ THIS IS NOT WHAT THE WIKIPEDIA ARTICLE IS DESCRIBING
```

`b` still refers to the same old `list` object, but `b[0]` now refers to the `99` object. You have simply replaced one of the references in the `list` referred to by `b` with a new reference to a different object.  You have **not** modified any objects that `a` points to!

```
id(a[0]) == id(b[0]) 
#False
```

False, because the `1` object is not the same object as the `99` object.

---

### **Part 2:  What the heck is that wikipedia article talking about, then?**

Here's an example of a copy operation where you are actually "modifying the memory address that one of B's fields point to", so you can see the subsequent change in the copied object.

```
a = [[1],[2],[3]]
```

`a` is a reference to a `list` object, but now the `list` object contains three references to `list` objects, which each contain a reference to an `int` object.

```
b = a[:]
```

As before, you've made `b` refer to a new, different `list` object, which refers to the SAME three `list` objects as are referred to in `a`.  Here's proof:

```
id(a) == id(b)
# False
```

False, because as before `a` and `b` are references to different `list` objects.

```
id(a[0]) == id(b[0]) 
#True
```

True, because as before, both `a[0]` and `b[0]` refer to the same object.  This time it's a `list` object, which is not **immutable**, unlike an `int` object - we can actually change the contents of the `list` object!  **Here's where it gets different:**

```
b[0][0] = 99
```

We did it - we changed the **contents** of the `list` object referred to by `b[0]`

```
a[0][0]
# 99 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!  Wikipedia doesn't need to be edited!
```

See?  The 'list' referred to by the `list` referred to by `a` now refers to the `99` object, rather than the `1` object, because it's the same `list` that you accessed with `b[0][0] = 99`.  Simple, huh ;)

```
id(a[0]) == id(b[0])
#True !!!
```

True, because although we changed the contents of what `a[0]` referenced, we did *not* change the reference itself in `a[0]` and `b[0]` - this is closer to what the Wikipedia article is describing in the 'Shallow Copy' section.

Answer (score 1):

> But why does writing to the index of "b" change the id.

Because they're different things now. If you were to check `a`, `a[0]` is still `1` rather than `99` because `b` was a copy. If you didn't want this behavior, you wouldn't do the copy:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a
>>> b[0] = 99
>>> a[0]
99
```

instead, you have this:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> b[0] = 99
>>> a[0]
1
```

Since you tagged `deepcopy`...it's something that only matters if your lists themselves contain mutable arguments. Say, for instance, you had:

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> b = a
>>> c = a[:]
>>> d = deepcopy(a)
```

So `a` is `b`, `c` is a shallow copy, and `d` is a deep copy.

```
>>> b[0] = 3
>>> a
[3, [3,4]]
>>> c
[[1,2], [3,4]]
>>> d
[[1,2], [3,4]]
```

`b` is the same as `a`, but the copies were unaffected.

```
>>> c[1][1] = 'hi'
>>> a
[3, [3, 'hi']]
>>> c
[[1, 2], [3, 'hi']]
```

If you replace the entries of `c`, `a` is unaffected. But if you still have the original lists *within* the entries, modifying one still shows up in the other. The nested lists are still the same.

```
>>> d[1][1] = 10
>>> a
[3, [3, 'hi']]
>>> d
[[1, 2], [3, 10]]
```

Since `d` was a deep copy, it copied the list as well as its nested lists, so we can modify it *and its elements* at will without worry about messing up the other copies.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy  "The disadvantage is if you modify the memory address that one of B's fields point to, you are also modifying what A's fields point to."   Why does'nt a[0] get changed in this case ?? Thx

Comment: You didn't modify any memory address? I'm not sure if that section's questionably written or if it's assuming properties of other languages dissimilar to Python's. http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables

Answer (score 1):

When you made a shallow copy of `a` to `b` ( `b = a[:]` ) you duplicated it.  `b` became a copy of `a` at a specific point in time -- it's a "snapshot" of a.

when you updated `b[0] = 99` , you updated `b` -- the copy of `a`.  you didn't update `a`.  that's the point of making a shallow (or deep) copy -- you want a new variable that has the same contents, this way you can make changes to the copy without affecting the original.

if you want `b[0] = 99` to affect `a` as well, then you don't want to "copy" `a`, you just want to refer to it by another name.  you'd use `b = a`.

Answer (score 1):

A list in Python contains references to its contents.

When you copy a list, using `a[:]` or the `copy` method, you create a new list with the *same* references.  What happens when you change an item of the original list depends on its type.

Mutable objects, such as lists, can be changed in-place (that's what makes them mutable).  Both lists still refer to the same object:

```
a = [[0],[1],[2]]
b = a[:]
a[0].append[1]
b[0] # >>> [0,1]
```

Integers, on the other hand, are *immutable*.  Changing an integer creates a new object, with a new id and reference.

```
a = [0, 1, 2]
b = a[:]
a[0] = 10
b[0] # >>> 0
```